# how to find when the API call is finished in angular

Tags: angular

I have a API call which i have to find when its finished to start calling the second api,I dont want to set timer because its not clear when the job is done,

```
this.http.get(`http://localhost:44301/consentinitiation/${this.qid}`)
.pipe(retryWhen(_ => {
  this.showIt=true
  return interval(1000)
}))
.subscribe(result => {result
console.log(result);
this.qrcodelink=result["qrCodeLink"];
setTimeout(() => {
    this.loadingSpinner=false;
}, 5000);

})
```

when the above call is finished i need to call the second API

```
        setTimeout(() => {
      this.http.get(`http://localhost:44301/consentinitiation/${this.qid}`)
        .pipe(retryWhen(_ => {
          this.showIt=true
          return interval(1000)
        }))
        .subscribe(result => {result
        console.log(result);
        this.edited=false;
        this.qrcodelink=result["qrCodeLink"];
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.loadingSpinner=false;
            
        }, 5000);
        
        })
      
    }, 30000);
```

its kind of conditional calling,when the first one is over start the second one

Comment: You're looking for [`.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

Comment: @ObsidianAge how does it work?

Comment: I linked the documentation stating exactly how it works.

Comment: @ObsidianAge can i ask the diffrence between .then and switchmap approach?

Comment: .then() doesnt help here, since we are not working with promises

Comment: @masali: 1) I would encourage you to read about [Promises](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-promises-explained/).  2) Once you understand Promises (and `then()`), consider using [Subscribe](https://rxjs.dev/guide/subscription), as Nikhil V S and Tobias S. suggested.  3) Under *NO* circumstances do you want to repeatedly check for gets status=="Received ".  This is called [polling](https://www.quora.com/What-is-polling-in-computer-science) - and polling is almost always  a poor design choice.

Comment: @paulsm4 may i ask why its poor?I should keep calling until the status is "Received"to achieve this i thout the only way is set timer(turned out the worst approach) but here they suggest polling,whats your suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't nest Observables inside each other. Use a **SwitchMap** instead.

```
this.http.get(`http://localhost:44301/consentinitiation/${this.qid}`).pipe(
    tap((result1) => { 
        /* use the result of first call here */ 
    }),
    switchMap((result1) => this.http.get(`http://localhost:44301/otherCall`))
).subscribe(result2 => { 
    /* use result of second call here */ 
})
```

Comment: why result1 is inside of the switch map? what does this part mean? switchMap((result1) => this.http.get(`http://localhost:44301/otherCall`))
)

Comment: In a RxJS pipe, results are passed down the chain. The result of the first API call gets passed down to tap and to the next switchMap. Because the next SwitchMap returns an Observable again, the result of this second call is passed further and ends up in the subscribe callback

Comment: and it means the second api call waits until the first one is finished?

Comment: yes, it does wait until there is a response to the first request

Comment: was this helpful?

Comment: not actually because the api should call the called until it gets  status=="Received ",thats sometimes take 10 seconds sometimes less,in the meantime it should keep calling until the Received is returned

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the second one after you get the result of first one, you may try:

```
firstapi.subscribe(
  (res) => {
    secondapi.subscribe();
  }
)
```